# the meta name="viewport" user-scalable=yes qusetion

Tags: android, web

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=2,user-scalable=yes">
```

I want to scale my page by this code ,but no use.who can teal me why